# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang3

I have the next code:

```
File root = new File("./build/classes");
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { root.toURI().toURL() });

Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName("events.Source", true,classLoader);



// JSON --> Java "Get the actual type"
Type listType = new DefaultParameterizedType(ArrayList.class, loadedClass);


Gson gson = new Gson();

ArrayList<loadedClass> resourcesList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```

When I run the program it shows the error **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder** I have the **commons-lang3-3.4.jar** file in my  **WEB-INF** --> **lib** directory, I don't know why it is showing this error when I call this statement:

```
System.out.println("Sending" + resourcesList.get(i).toString());
```

The console output is:

```
jun 11, 2015 11:31:32 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
GRAVE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not     be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder
at eventos.Posicion.toString(Unknown Source)
at eventos.ParserFromFile.parsearListaRecursosDesdeFichero(ParserFromFile.java:132)
at eventos.Analisis.faseDos(Analisis.java:126)
at resources.ConfiguracionResource.addObjetoJSON(ConfiguracionResource.java:213)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 45 more

jun 11, 2015 11:31:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
 GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [Jersey REST Service] en el                  contexto con ruta [/EasyCEP] lanzó la excepción [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder] con causa raíz
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at eventos.Posicion.toString(Unknown Source)
at eventos.ParserFromFile.parsearListaRecursosDesdeFichero(ParserFromFile.java:132)
at eventos.Analisis.faseDos(Analisis.java:126)
at resources.ConfiguracionResource.addObjetoJSON(ConfiguracionResource.java:213)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please provide more code, show what is in the resourceList, provide complete stack trace. Just give us more info - this will help us to help you

Comment: Is it a normal java class or web application?

Comment: @Abhi It´s a web app

Comment: Have you tried changing your import to org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder as Michael suggested?

Comment: @Abhi actually I need both of them because of a maven dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// We change the classpath, adding a new jar to the  ClassLoader.(org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder)
    try {
        // We get the ClassLoader and their method addURL()
        URLClassLoader classLoader = ((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader
                .getSystemClassLoader());
        Method metodoAdd = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL",
                new Class[] { URL.class });
        metodoAdd.setAccessible(true);

        // The URL of the jar we want to add
        URL url = new URL(
                "file:///C:/Users/****/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/*****/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar");

        // the method addURL is invoked passing that jar´s url 
        metodoAdd.invoke(classLoader, new Object[] { url });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the API it seems that in 3.3 version you should import org.apache.commons.**lang3**.builder.ToStringBuilder and not org.apache.commons.**lang**.builder.ToStringBuilder

So i'm guessing you compile with a previous version (2?) of commons-lang and use a newer in your web server.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.3/

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/